# Mark all messages as read in the Telegram group from Python

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

How can I **mark** all **messages** as **read** in a particular chat/group/supergroup with the Telegram library in Python?

What is it for?

I joined several large Telegram groups where I may in the future seek information...

But I don't want to see unread messages in these groups (and the increasing total counter)

Answer (score 0):

Just get a list of messages and use [send_read_acknowledge](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.send_read_acknowledge):

```py
messages = ...
await client.send_read_acknowledge(chat, messages, clear_mentions=True)
...
```

Comment: Note that getting the list of messages is not necessary. You can simply pass the chat and clear mentions to read everything.